# NoClassDefFoundError - javax/el/ExpressionFactory - Tomcat 7 and Spring MVC

Tags: spring, jsp, tomcat, spring-mvc

I am trying to deploy to tomcat 7 a little Spring MVC app, and I am getting the dreaded exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ExpressionFactory
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspApplicationContextImpl.getExpressionFactory(JspApplicationContextImpl.java:108)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.<init>(Validator.java:514)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateExDirectives(Validator.java:1795)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:217)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

I don't see any usual suspects in my WEB-INF/lib that is deployed (servlet-api.jar, el-api.jar, etc.).

Here is my pom.xml file:

```
<!-- Servlet -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I am basically trying to load a simple jsp page.  I know that Tomcat is choking compiling the jsp page using Jasper because it is hitting this Class Loader issue, but I can't figure out why.

My only guess is that either I need to package a library that I am not, or perhaps add a library to the tomcat/lib.

Here are the list of jars in my WEB-INF/lib

```
activation-1.1.jar
antlr-2.7.6.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar
aspectjrt-1.6.6.jar
aspectjweaver-1.6.6.jar
commons-collections-3.2.jar
commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar
commons-io-1.4.jar
commons-lang-2.1.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
commons-pool-1.3.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
ehcache-core-2.3.0.jar
freemarker-2.3.15.jar
groovy-all-1.8.5.jar
guava-12.0.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.0.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final.jar
hsqldb-1.8.0.7.jar
jacks_2.10-2.1.4.jar
jackson-annotations-2.1.4.jar
jackson-core-2.1.4.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.9.jar
jackson-databind-2.1.4.jar
javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar
javax.inject-1.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.0.CR2.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar
jettison-1.1.jar
joda-time-1.6.2.jar
jsr305-1.3.9.jar
log4j-1.2.17.jar
logback-classic-1.0.7.jar
logback-core-1.0.7.jar
mail-1.4.6-rc1.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar
ognl-3.0.5.jar
scala-compiler-2.10.1.jar
scala-library-2.10.1.jar
scala-reflect-2.10.0.jar
scalap-2.10.1.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar
snakeyaml-1.11.jar
spring-aop-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-batch-admin-manager-1.3.0.BUILD-20130514.094516-16.jar
spring-batch-admin-resources-1.3.0.BUILD-20130514.094516-17.jar
spring-batch-core-2.2.0.BUILD-20130514.030108-700.jar
spring-batch-infrastructure-2.2.0.BUILD-20130514.030108-714.jar
spring-batch-integration-1.3.0.BUILD-20130514.094516-17.jar
spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-integration-core-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-integration-file-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-integration-groovy-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-integration-http-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-integration-jms-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-integration-jmx-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-integration-mail-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-integration-scripting-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-integration-stream-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-integration-twitter-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-integration-ws-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-integration-xml-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-jms-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-oxm-1.5.9.jar
spring-oxm-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-retry-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-scala-1.0.0.M2.jar
spring-security-config-3.2.0.M1.jar
spring-security-core-3.2.0.M1.jar
spring-security-crypto-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar
spring-social-core-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-social-twitter-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-ws-core-1.5.9.jar
spring-xml-1.5.9.jar
thymeleaf-2.0.15.jar
thymeleaf-layout-dialect-1.0.5.jar
thymeleaf-spring3-2.0.15.jar
wsdl4j-1.6.1.jar
xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar
xstream-1.3.jar
```

Comment: `javax.el.ExpressionFactory` lives in `el-api.jar`. Do you have that jar in the `tomcat/lib`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I had another answer that was deleted.  But it turns out, the previous fellow was correct in that I needed el-api and el-impl.  I undeployed everything from tomcat, and restarted the tomcat instance, then the deploy happened fine.